# Azure Functions - Kafka Trigger and Output Binding - Consume exactly-once

Tags: python, apache-kafka, azure-functions

I'm testing the [Kafka Trigger and Output Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-kafka?tabs=in-process%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-python) in Azure Functions to consume a topic and write the message to another topic, very simple code.

But when I enable the auto-scale feature and the function provision new instances, I'm losing the 'exactly-once' feature and apparently some messages are being delivered to more than one instance.

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.6.0, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "kafkaTrigger",
      "name": "kafkaTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "brokerList": "%PEP_BEES_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP%",
      "topic": "%PEP_BEES_KAFKA_SOURCE_TOPIC%",
      "consumerGroup": "%PEP_BEES_KAFKA_SOURCE_TOPIC_CONSUMER_GROUP%"
    },
    {
      "type": "kafka",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "kafkaOutput",
      "brokerList": "%PEP_BEES_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP%",
      "topic": "%PEP_BEES_KAFKA_DESTINATION_TOPIC%"
    }
  ]
}
```

**init**.py

```
import logging, json
from azure.functions import KafkaEvent
import azure.functions as func
import typing

def main(kafkaTrigger : typing.List[KafkaEvent], kafkaOutput: func.Out[str]):

    message = json.loads(str(kafkaTrigger.get_body().decode('utf-8')))

    input_msg = str(message['Value'])

    kafkaOutput.set(input_msg)
```

As you can see in the image below, the 'test-topic-output' (destination) has more messages than the 'test-topic' (source), indicating that sometimes more than one instance is consuming a message:
[Message count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISmKp.png)

If I disable the auto-scaling feature, this behavior does not happen.

I just need that the 'exactly-once' feature works even with the function auto-scale enabled, to have an elastic environment.

### EDIT

I just found out some erros during the Kafka Trigger processing:
[Kafka Trigger errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWgw7.png)

```
Confluent.Kafka.KafkaException:
at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.SafeKafkaHandle.StoreOffsets (Confluent.Kafka, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=12c514ca49093d1e)
at Confluent.Kafka.Consumer2.StoreOffset (Confluent.Kafka, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=12c514ca49093d1e) at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka.AsyncCommitStrategy2.Commit (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka/Trigger/AsyncCommitStrategy.cs:28)
at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka.FunctionExecutorBase`2.Commit (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Kafka/Trigger/FunctionExecutorBase.cs:87)
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I disable the auto-scaling feature, this behavior does not happen

If you scale up, that wouldn't prevent records that were just consumed from existing inputs from being sent to output function.

You'd need a way to catch a consumer group rebalance within the function, and upon that action, then don't send to the output... Given that Azure doesn't expose Kafka native API, then its unlikely that is possible. You also would need to control when the function commits its consumer offsets (assuming `PEP_BEES_KAFKA_SOURCE_TOPIC_CONSUMER_GROUP` is a constant value); e.g. if it commits before `kafkaTrigger.get_body()`, then you should get less "extras", but if it commits after `kafkaOutput.set()`, then you'll have more upon scaling up...

Rather than use Python or serverless functions for replicating topics, you can use MirrorMaker or Kafka Streams instead.

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, I just edited the question with some errors that I found in the Kafka Trigger processing

Comment: Looks like it's having issues committing offsets, but that doesn't really change my answer. If an offset commit fails, then you definitely will see duplicate records being processed.

Answer (score 0):

I had noticed similar behavior of the kafka triggers consuming duplicate events when the scaling up the instance count (and surprisingly also during scale down). In batch mode with batch size of 50, its always the same 50 events that get read by 2 instance. I have also noticed this happens only once per instance scale up or (down).

One of the potential solution you can explore is using a warmup trigger that run during scale-out operation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-warmup?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-python